# Assigning a singleton to a variable (Swift)

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, singleton, retain-cycle, retaincount

Is it an anti-pattern to have the following code?

I want to have the singleton (ClassB) as a variable so that I have some sort of dependency injection while still using a singleton. But I have been hinted that without having *mySingleton* as weak I could have memory leaks.
But I cannot think of any such scenario...

```swift
class ClassA {
    var mySingleton: ClassB? = ClassB.shared

    deinit {
        print("deinit A")
    }
}

class ClassB {
static let shared = ClassB()

    deinit {
        print("deinit B")
    }
 }

var a1: ClassA? = ClassA()
var b1: ClassB? = ClassB()

a1?.mySingleton = b1

a1 = nil
b1 = nil
```

EDIT: made improvements to the code although they irrelevant to the question which is if it is an anti-pattern to assign a singleton to a variable and specifically it if can cause memory leaks

Comment: `shared` isn't really a singleton in the sense that you can create any number of `ClassB` instances and you can also modify the reference of `shared`. You should declare `shared` as immutable using the `let` keyword and make the initialiser of `ClassB` private if you want to have a true singleton. Moreover, why make `ClassB` inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: If you want to create a _singleton class_, you need to declare the **initialiser of that class as private**, so that we cannot use any object other than _singleton object_

Comment: @DávidPásztor @ShubhamBakshi oops I hastily created an example to showcase the use case I wanted to ask about and neglected these things. Thank you for your comment but my main question is if the assignment of `shared` to a variable can cause memory leaks